# Clearance gem Auth - undefined local variable or method `_current_user_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the clearance gem for authentication in my rails app and i'm trying to user the current user method in my create method. I'm getting this error.

>
NameError in ReportsController#create
undefined local variable or method `_current_user_id' for #

Here is the create method code

```
def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)
    @report.user_id = current_user_id
    @report.patient_id = @patient.id

    if @report.save
        redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: For a start, looks like you should using `current_user.id` helper method.

Comment: By seeing the git page https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance. I think you have to use the ```current_user.id```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params) do |r|
      r.user = current_user
      r.patient = @patient
    end

    if @report.save
      redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

There is no need to explicitly map ids when assigning associations in Rails - just pass the record itself instead.

If you really want to get the id use `current_user.id`.